# Is it possible to make an interval $[a, b]$ a group without identifying the two endpoints.

Tags: group-theory

If we identify the endpoint, we have $S^1$, but is it a group if we treat the endpoints as different points?

This question can also be generalized to higher dimensions. What about a square? If we identify the boundary, we can have a torus $S^1\times S^1$, but if we are not allowed, will it be a group?

Comment: Pick your favourite bijection $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and define a group structure through $x,y\in [a,b]$ $$x\cdot y:= g(x)+g(y).$$ Then $([a,b], \cdot)$ is (by construction) a group isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R}, +)$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven that should be $g^{-1}\left(g(x)+g(y)\right).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, thanks for catching the mistake!

Comment: There is a continuous group structure on $(0,1)$ but not on $[0,1].$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it a group as a set (this is trivial), but if you mean making it a topological group then it can't be done. A simple way to see this is that because left multiplication by elements of the group would define homeomorphisms, you could translate a neighborhood of the identity element of the group to homeomorphic neighborhoods of all elements of the group. In other words, a topological group must "look the same" if you look at it near any element of the group.

The circle and the torus have this property but the closed interval $ [0, 1] $ does not, since $ [0, a) $ for $ a > 0 $ is not homeomorphic to an open interval. You can see this because removing the point $ 0 $ from $ [0, a) $ doesn't disconnect it, but removing *any point* from an open interval would disconnect it.

Comment: This is basically the statement that a topological group must be homogeneous, ruling out $[a,b]$ as a topological group.